# How to disable Fullcalendar's automatic width / padding of multi-day events

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I have built an app using Fullcalendar, and I want to disable FullCalendar's automatic margins/paddings/width/whatever causes multi-day events to extend a few pixels past the edge of the single-day events, so that they are all visually flush.  How can I go about doing this, preferably without tampering with the original fullcalendar.js file? If that is the only way, I will accept that, of course.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the whitespace it leaves on the right side of the event, I needed that to be gone too. Only way I found of doing that was by removing this line from the original plugin file:

```
columnRight -= columnWidth * .025;
```

Comment: It's more like the multi-day event extends beyond the edge of the single-day events by about 2px. It seems to be controlled by the left: X px css variable, although it's unclear where this is being done.